# Simple Event Listener in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript

I don't see where I am going wrong with this Event Listener,

```js
function getInfo() {
  let name = prompt("What is your first name?");
  let age = prompt("What is your age?");

  let applyNow = document.querySelector("button");

  applyNow.addEventListener("click", getInfo);
}
```

```html
<section> <button>Apply Now</button>
</section>
```

Comment: Your `addEventListener` is inside the listener function itself. Move it outside else it'll never get attached.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The addEventListener is encased inside the function, so it'll only be added once `getInfo()` is called, a Catch22. You need to put the addEventListener and the applyNow variable outside of the function.

```js
function getInfo() {
  let name = prompt("What is your first name?");
  let age = prompt("What is your age?");
}
let applyNow = document.querySelector("button");
applyNow.addEventListener("click", getInfo);
```

```html
<button>applyNow</button>
```

Comment: Please do not answer such obvious questions that have already been answered in the comments.